# Linq distinct columns plus count from datatable

Tags: c#, linq

Would like to pull a distinct list based on server name and resource group but provide a channel count as well. Datatable example:

```
resourceGroup serverName    circuitId   channelId
SIP           win1234       0           1
SIP           win1234       0           2
TDM           win5678       0           35      
TDM           win5678       0           36
SIP           win5678       4           47
TDM           win1234       8           56
```

With the expected results:

```
serverName  resourceGroup   channelCount
win1234     SIP             2
win1234     TDM             1
win5678     SIP             1
win5678     TDM             2
```

Comment: Please show your work so far. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: What you want is a group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/72kUgW) for you.

You are looking for a GroupBy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // create the records
        TestRecords testRecord1 = new TestRecords(){Id = 1, ResourceGroup = "SIP", ServerName = "win1234", CircuitId = 0, ChannelId = 1};
        TestRecords testRecord2 = new TestRecords(){Id = 2, ResourceGroup = "SIP", ServerName = "win1234", CircuitId = 0, ChannelId = 2};
        TestRecords testRecord3 = new TestRecords(){Id = 3, ResourceGroup = "TDM", ServerName = "win5678", CircuitId = 0, ChannelId = 35};
        TestRecords testRecord4 = new TestRecords(){Id = 4, ResourceGroup = "TDM", ServerName = "win5678", CircuitId = 0, ChannelId = 36};
        TestRecords testRecord5 = new TestRecords(){Id = 5, ResourceGroup = "SIP", ServerName = "win5678", CircuitId = 4, ChannelId = 47};
        TestRecords testRecord6 = new TestRecords(){Id = 6, ResourceGroup = "TDM", ServerName = "win1234", CircuitId = 8, ChannelId = 56};

        // create an empty list of TestRecords to hold the records above
        List<TestRecords> listTestRecords = new List<TestRecords>();

        // add records to list
        listTestRecords.Add(testRecord1);
        listTestRecords.Add(testRecord2);
        listTestRecords.Add(testRecord3);
        listTestRecords.Add(testRecord4);
        listTestRecords.Add(testRecord5);
        listTestRecords.Add(testRecord6);

        // group the records by ServerName
        var resultGrouped = listTestRecords.GroupBy(x => new{x.ServerName, x.ResourceGroup}).ToList();

        // select the items you need based off of the groupings
        var result = resultGrouped.Select(x => new{Server = x.Key.ServerName, ResourceGroup = x.Key.ResourceGroup, CountChannel = x.Count()}).ToList();

        foreach(var item in result){
            Console.WriteLine(item.Server + " " + item.ResourceGroup + " " + item.CountChannel);
        }

        // Result:
        //win1234 SIP 2
        //win5678 TDM 2
        //win5678 SIP 1
       // win1234 TDM 1
    }
}

public class TestRecords
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ResourceGroup {get;set;}
    public string ServerName {get;set;}
    public int CircuitId {get;set;} 
    public int ChannelId {get;set;}
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use group by.

**select  serverName, resourceGroup, count(1)
 from TABLE_Name 
group by serverName, resourceGroup 
having count(1) >= 1;**